# malloc and free pointer in C functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, free

I use `malloc` inside my function and then return the pointer. Where do I have to free the memory with function `free(ret_str)`? Inside the `function_name()` method or outside? And how to do that?

Function:

```
char* function_name(void)
{
  int state = 3;                                                                
  //char *ret_str = malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
  Send("string");
  state = wait_response();
  if(state == 1)
  {
    char *ret_str = malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(ret_str, rx_buffer+(strcspn(rx_buffer, "?")+5));
    strncpy(ret_str+strcspn(ret_str, "\r"), " ", 1);
    strncpy(ret_str+strcspn(ret_str, "\n"), ret_str+strcspn(ret_str, "\n")+3, 2);
    ret_str[strcspn(ret_str, "\n")] = '\0';
    empty_buffer(p_rx_buffer);  
    return ret_str;
  }
  else
  {
    empty_buffer(p_rx_buffer);          
    return "D_ERROR";
  } 
}
```

Function call:

```
char *current_setting;
current_setting = function_name();
free(current_setting);
```

Comment: It all depends on the lifetime of your object.

Comment: Do `malloc` after entering the `if` statement else you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would it be possible to `free` the memory inside the function, when it has to return that memory?

There are two ways of handling this:

1. Have two functions: One to allocate, and one to free, mimicking the `malloc` and `free` calls.
2. Have a function that allocates, but leaves it up to the caller to free.

---

By the way, your function as shown in the question will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if `state` is not equal to `1` and you later try to `free` the returned pointer (when and where doesn't matter). The reason is that you return a pointer to a string literal, and those haven't been allocated by `malloc` and can't be passed to `free`.

<strike>If the `state` is not equal to `1` then you will also have a memory leak, as you allocate memory but don't return a pointer to it, so the pointer is lost.</strike>

Comment: I changed the malloc and added free function in My question. Pleas can You look at it and tell if is this better?

Comment: @user3635703 So you decided to go with solution 2 in my list. That will work, if ***and only if*** `wait_response` returns `1` inside the function.